# How to remove space before first item of gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to remove space before and below the image which is item of custom gallery. I have tried setting spacing but it removes space between two images. I want to remove space before first image and end space after last image. 
    Also there is some spacing at the bottom of the gallery images.

Space is at Left side of the image and bottom of the image. I want image width to fill the screen.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:coverflow="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/homeCoverflowWrapper"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >

        <com.bhaskar.util.CoverFlow
            android:id="@+id/coverflow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeCoverflowWrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/red1"
        android:weightSum="1" >
        <!-- android:background="@*android:color/background_dark"  -->


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_arrow_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@*android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/lft_arrow_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRight"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_arrow_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@*android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code? Pictures? Layouts?

Comment: Post the code for `ListView` item layout

Comment: It is not related to ListView... Images are loaded in Custom Gallyview com.bhaskar.util.CoverFlow..

Comment: @Bhaskar:make id which is main_holder make the android:layout_height="match_parent".. I think it would help you